# how to pass text areas values to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a view with multiple text areas which are generated in a loop. I want to pass the values on form submit using jQuery. I use the below code to call the action result:

```
var url = "/Template/DATA";
var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">' +
    '<input type="text" name="TemplateID" value="' + TemplateID + '" />' +
    '<input type="text" name="SectionID" value="' + SectionID + '" />' +
    '<input type="text" name="StartDate" value="' + StartDate + '" />' +
    '<input type="text" name="EndDate" value="' + EndDate + '" />' +
    // here i want to pass the values of the text areas to the action result
    '</form>');
$('body').append(form);
form.submit();
```

Comment: It looks like you would be better off using AJAX instead of dynamically building the HTML of a form, appending it to the DOM and immediately submitting it.

Comment: What is the model of the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using using html/jquery/ajax?

```
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="template" name="TemplateID" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="section" name="SectionID" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="start" name="StartDate" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="end "name="EndDate" value="" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>;
```

Give values to the from with on document load and serialize data for sending.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('#template').val('Template');
    $('#section').val('section');
    $('#start').val('start');
    $('#end').val('end');

$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'js/ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.status);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
            console.log(data.status);
        }
    });
});
});
```

And then access data in php like you would access any other post data

```
if($_POST){

    $template = $_POST['template'];
    $section = $_POST['section'];
    $start = $_POST['start'];
    $end = $_POST['end'];
    /** Do whatever with this data */ 

    $result = $template . $section . $start . $end
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ok', 'result' => $content));

} else {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error'));
}
```